# Can't test successfully for view that puts form data in session

Tags: django

I'm trying to test a view that stores validated form data in the session. However when I try to test this I get back None for the session value and the error:

AssertionError: 'example_postcode' != None

The test is:

```
class TestSignup(TestCase):

    def test_postcode(self):
        postcode = 'example_postcode'
        self.client.post('/users/postcode/',  {'postcode': postcode})
        self.assertEqual(postcode, self.client.session.get('postcode'))
```

the view is:

```
@require_http_methods(['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST'])
def postcode_view(request,):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostcodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session.update(form.cleaned_data)
            return redirect('users:signup_2')
    else:
        form = form_class()
    context.update({'form': form})
    return render(request, 'pages/signup_postcode.html', context)
```

form

```
class PostcodeForm(forms.Form):
    postcode = GBPostcodeField(label='Please enter your postcode',
                               error_messages={'invalid': 'Please enter a valid postcode'})
```

Comment: Are you sure that the form was valid and that the `request.session.update()` line was run?

Comment: Maybe try to recover the response of your post first; then assert the session on the response object?

Comment: Ah it was just the trailing slash in the address that was missing. Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above by others confirmed the test was largely correct and the error was a trailing slash which is now updated above.